# Autocommit is causing pandas to_sql to fail

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy

I've got a problem with my engine parameters:

```
    import pyodbc
    import pandas as pd
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    import urllib


    conn_str = (
        r'Driver=ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server;'
        r'Server=Saturn;'
        r'Database=ExperienceRating2019;'
        r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
    )
    quoted_conn_str = urllib.parse.quote_plus(conn_str)
    engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(quoted_conn_str)).execution_options(autocommit=True)
    cnxn = engine.connect()

    splitpoint = 17000
    excel_file = "#2 DRATIO RUN.xlsx"
    d_ratio_sheet = "D RATIO & ELR"

    d_ratio = pd.read_excel(open(excel_file,'rb'),sheet_name = d_ratio_sheet)
    d_ratio.to_sql("d_ratio", cnxn, if_exists = 'replace')
```

I will get the following error:

DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('HY010', '[HY010] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Function sequence error (0) (SQLFetch)') (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/dbapi)

If I change my engine to lose the autocommit

```
    engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(quoted_conn_str))
```

The error goes away(yay!) but later in my code, where I execute a SP, it will no longer commit:

```
    engine.execute("sp_refresh_inputs")
```

**Question:**How can I change my change my connection so that both pandas and sqlalchemy work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using two engines, one for pandas and one for sqlalchemy:

```
cnxn = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(quoted_conn_str))
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(quoted_conn_str)).execution_options(autocommit=True)
```